# How to edit fields of a table?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have a table to show a long list of items, I am wondering how I can edit the fields and submit the form to update them?

```
 <form name="edit" method="POST" action="edit">
    <table border="4">
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${basket.items}" var="item">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="item.id" value="${item.id}"/>  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input label="Price" value="${item.product.price}"/>
                        <br/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
    this is a new one
   <input id="edit" type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You might need to use ajax from what you have posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Struts2, with JSTL and EL instead of Struts Tags and OGNL... is there a particular reason that forces you to drop most of the framework mechanics ?

That said, your inputs aren't valid (no type specified) and the "this is a new one" sentence in the HTML seems to indicate the willing to insert a new row, instead of editing the existing entres. Your description and your code seem to ask two different things... to insert a new one, just make a call to another method of the action (or another action) called "add" instead of "edit", sending one single element and adding it to the collection. No need to use AJAX here...

If instead, the question is really:

> how I can edit the fields and submit the form to update them ?

this is the way:

```
<s:form method="POST" action="edit">
    <table border="4">
        <tbody>
            <s:iterator value="basket.items" var="item" status="ctr">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <s:textfield name="item[%{#ctr.index}].id" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <s:textfield name="item[%{#ctr.index}].product.price" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </tbody>
    </table> 
    <s:submit value="Edit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I used your answer but the format of generate html table is different please have a look at my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647284/how-to-format-a-table

Comment: Yep, Simple Theme FTW

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you make an AJAX call using jquery to update the new one. And then in the success handler you can append the new line to the existing table. Before doing that you need to give your table proper ids so that its easier to use JQUERY.

```
var newLine = document.createElement("tr");
var cellName = document.createElement("td");
$(cellName).text("itemId");
$(newLine).append(cellName);
// similarly create other td's
$("#modelTable").append(newLine);// replace modelTable by the id of your table
```