# Struts2 Checkbox: How to set value back to Bean

Tags: java, struts2

I have a folowing pojo form bean class:-

```
class A{

int role;
List<String> roleList;
List<B> menuList;
public setMenuList(List<B> menuList)
{
    this.menuList=menuList;
}
}
```

My menuList is of type B so the Following is the second pojo class B:-

```
class B{
            private String displayName;
        private boolean  viewCheckBox;
        private boolean  addCheckBox;
        private boolean  editCheckBox;
        private boolean  deleteCheckBox;
        private boolean  downloadCheckBox;
        private String menuKey;
        private int menuActionFlag;
        private int menuId;
        private int menuActive;
        private int menuLevel;
            // setter and getters
}
```

IN my action class i am creating object of class A and calling setter and getter of A.

```
public class MenuAction
{
    A a=new A();
    //getter and setter of A
    public list getAllMenus(){
     // populating menuList  from the database
    }


 public String save()
{
    a=getA();
    System.out.println("In Save"+a);
            List<B> list=a.getMenuList();
    System.out.println("MenuList is"+ list); // **  here i should get the menuList from jsp but its returning Null**
    //  code to save the changes into database

}

}
```

My jsp is showing a tabular form containg many checkboxes  state of checkboxes are in class B and class A contains List menuList as an attribute.. In jsp i am iterating from the menuList and depending upon the status of the boolean var in B i am setting the checkboxes..

```
     <c:forEach var="b" items="${a.menuList}"varStatus="status">
    <c:if test="${b.getMenuLevel()==2}">

    <tr>

    <td align="center">
    <c:out value="${b.isViewCheckBox()}"></c:out> 

        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${b.isViewCheckBox()}">
            <c:out value="${b.isViewCheckBox()}"></c:out>
            <p>
            <s:checkbox name="b.viewCheckBox" id="v_%{menuKey}" fieldValue="b.viewCheckBox" value="#attr.b.viewCheckBox"/>
                                                    </p>
        </c:when>


<c:otherwise>
            <p><s:checkbox name="b.viewCheckBox" id="v_%{menuKey}" fieldValue="b.viewCheckBox" value="#attr.b.viewCheckBox"
            disabled="true" />                                          </p>                                        </c:otherwise>
```

While I click on save i go in save method of the action class where i am getting menuList as null.... I think the List is of type B that's why its showing null.. its not getting B... or maybe menuList inside bean is not getting set..
How to solve this problem..

Comment: Problem could be in your data fetching or you haven't defined getter/setter in your action class.

Comment: I have defined getter and setter of bean in my action class ..
As you can see in my Question  I am getting the menuList as null...

Comment: I think You have defined in your POJO class not in your Action class. create getter/setter in action it should work.

Comment: What are getting in your action, have debug your code? are you getting list with data in your Action class.

Comment: I have created and defined the setter and getter of POJO in action class.. I tried to debug it i am getting List as null..
Can it be because menuList is of type B where as my form model is A

Comment: you have created  A a=new A(); and getting list from roleMenuActionMappingBean. bit confusing

Comment: hey sorry for that I forgot to edit that part now its edited

Comment: It was just a typing mistake now i have updated it

Comment: Can you post your data retrieval code coz you are just creating a constructor and it always give you null.

Comment: I used that also but still its not working

Comment: What is IteratorStatus.index

Comment: @AndreaLigios how to use iterator status.. can you change the code above and reply to me...

Comment: @AnkitDuggal If you are using Struts2, why are u not using struts2 tags

Comment: @AnkitDuggal http://stackoverflow.com/a/19630589/1654265

Comment: @AndreaLigios I have done as specified but its showing me **menulist which is not null But contain null values**...

Comment: and ? Expected result ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios  I want the menuList to contain the changes made by user in the form..
**All the attributes of class B should be set** according to changes in form... as **menuList is of type B**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there are various things to consider :

1. Please don't mix in the GUI (struts2 tags & jstl)
2. The name is wrong according to what is expected in the action.

`<s:checkbox name="b.viewCheckBox" id="v_%{menuKey}" fieldValue="b.viewCheckBox" value="#attr.b.viewCheckBox"
            disabled="true" />`

The above will work if you have a setter for

`private B b;`

But you're having the setter for `List<B> menuList;` and hence the name of the checkbox should be

`<s:checkbox name="menuList[0].viewCheckBox" id="v_%{menuKey}" fieldValue="menuList[0].viewCheckBox" value="#attr.b.viewCheckBox"
            disabled="true" />`

Comment: I have done the changes you specified as option 2 . still the MenuList is showing me Empty in the action.. Might be because I am having a setter for menuList in Class A BUt in action I am having  setter and getter for A obj...

Comment: How to solve this problem I My list is in the bean A I am iterating the list using 
`<s:iterator var="menuList" value="a.menuList" status="status"> `
In action i am creating obj of A a=new A(); and having setter and getter of a

Comment: change name to `name="a.menuList[0].viewCheckBox"`

Comment: Done that now the problem is it is setting the menuList with null values. I am getting the menuList but with null values.. Might be because menuList contains List of B objects There is 1 object for every Checkbox...